# Xcode: Organizing Apps with Multiple Storyboards (TableView)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, storyboard

We have an [iPhone App](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/id530983394?mt=8&affId=2101225) in the company.

In this app I created the menu with TableViewController.

All controllers / images etc are in a storyboard.

The whole makes Xcode unfortunately very slow and small changes take a long time.

Now I want to create a custom storyboard for each menu item.

This means that to another storyboard I would like to link from one menu item from the table view.

Unfortunately, I do not know how can I achieve this.

On [Youtube I found a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QhNdvCE9jVg) to realize this with a view controller and buttons. Unfortunately I do not get it out, it adapt to the table view.

Can someone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Yours sincerely.

Comment: Please indicate what your specific problem was with adapting the method in the video that uses buttons to a table view. There's not really much difference. With a button, the code goes in its action method. With a table view, the code goes in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: My problem is that I'm not a programmer. I can not transfer it to the table view. I always need an example with my problem. I can program neither C nor Swift. The app is mainly composed of the GUI. The rest I culled and adjusted me. I have tried the code to write to the TableViewController.h and TableViewController.m, rather than in the view controller as shown in the video. But if I want to assign the TouchIn event in the TableCell, I'm stuck. Because this is not available for selection in the GUI, the TableCell. I Need a Little Code help.